# Simulink: undefined reference

Tags: c, linux, simulink, raspberry-pi2

Simulink R2016a on Windows-10 64-bit errors:

```
 - undefined reference to serialGetchar 
 - undefined reference to serialOpen
```

As I understand it: these two functions are of the library wiringpi, which was  configured in make-file as shown below.  Checked to see if the appropriate library is present (Why is filename is red?):

[image]

Compiling with R2015a R2015b on Win10 did not suffer these errors.  Where to begin with troubleshooting?  Any suggestions \ questions to diagnose root-cause are appreciated.

**Error Message:**
[image: Error Message]
**serialGetchar:**
[image: serialGetchar]
**serialOpen:**
[image: serialOpen]
**lwiringpi configured in make-file**

[image]

Configuring xmakefilesetup with:

**C:\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2016a\toolbox\realtime\targets\linux\registry\gcc_linuxremotebuild.m**

Comment: R2016b: xmakefilesetup removed